# Determining when combinatorial sums are zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, additive-combinatorics

To keep things simple with a specific example, we ask:

Prove that $\displaystyle\ a_n:=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k!} (-1)^{n-k}$ is zero if and only if $n=1$. (Or find a counter-example).

In fact, determining when said sequence is positive and negative is even more challenging. We list the first few calculations, to show that it does not alternate in sign:

$\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty=\{1, 0, -\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{9}, -\frac{5}{192}, \frac{7}{1800}, -\frac{37}{103680}, \frac{17}{2116800}, \frac{887}{232243200}, \ldots\}$

Posted a related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211767/determing-signs-of-taylor-coefficients-in-entire-functions

Comment: Your numbers seem to be not $a_n$ as you defined it but $a_n/n!$.  Of course that doesn't affect the signs.

Comment: Yes, just realized that. Although the questions and analysis are don't change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Maple, $a_n$ (with the revised definition) is $(-1)^n \text{LaguerreL}(n,1)/n!$.
I don't know asymptotics of this as $n \to \infty$,
but maybe something can be obtained from an integral representation of LaguerreL.
The plot is quite suggestive.

[image]

Comment: The generating function of $(-1)^n \text{Laguerre}(n,1)$ is $e^{\frac{t}{1+t}}/(1+t)=e^{-t^2/2 + 2t^3/3 + O(t^4)}$ (see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials). That should be enough to derive asymptotics and in particular, the sign.

Comment: This should settle the vanishing question, at any rate: according to this paper https://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/fila.ps
Schur showed in 1929 that the Laguerre polynomials are always irreducible, so in particular cannot have a rational root once $n>1$.

Comment: And the asymptotics were also studied: Theorem 8.22.1 (due to Fejér) in Szegő's "Orthogonal Polynomials" implies that $\text{Laguerre}(n,1) = \sqrt{e/\pi} n^{-1/4} \cos(2\sqrt{n}-\frac{\pi}{4}) + O(n^{-3/4})$. So the sign is related to $2\sqrt{n} \mod {2\pi}$. If you're worried about the error term being large compared to the $\cos$, Perron also provided an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: Good graph and comments. Very good stuff. I thought this might turn into another dead post, so I am going to post the problem I have been wondering in another thread.

Comment: Non-vanishing can be established by simpler means, after multiplying by $n!^2$ we get an integer which is 1 modulo $n$.

Answer (score 8):

(Non-vanishing is established by multiplying by $n!^2$ and getting an expression which is 1 modulo $n$.)

Robert Israel's answer and the comments following it settle your problem completely, but here's a general strategy that often works:

Suppose you have a sum of the form $S(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(n,k)$, where $f$ is "hyper-geometric" in the sense that $f(n+1,k)/f(n,k), f(n,k+1)/f(n,k)$ are rational functions.

1. Find the maximum of $|f(n,k)|$ as a function of $k$ ($n$ fixed). This is rather easy because $|f(n,k+1)|/|f(n,k)|$ is the absolute value of a rational function. In your specific problem, it is $\frac{n-k}{(k+1)^2}$, so $|f(n,k)|$ increases for $k \lesssim \sqrt{n}$ and then it decreases. The sign of the largest term is usually the resulting sign of the sum.
2. Suppose the maximum is attained at $k=M(n)$. Focus on estimating the sum around $k=M(n)$ (the rest of the terms should be easier to bound, as we know they are smaller, the decay is exponential usually). Specifically, Stirling's approximation is usually enough for estimating $\sum_{k=-\Delta}^{\Delta} f(n,M(n)+k)$ - plugging Stirling and using some Taylor series estimates ($\Delta$ is chosen so that the Taylor series estimates are valid), we get a sum that can sometimes be evaluated even by comparing to a Riemann's integral.

This is a rather elementary approach; Asymptotic methods such as steepest descent can yield *much* better results if you can express your sum as the coefficient of some analytic function. This can be done in your case as we have the relevant generating function: $e^{\frac{t}{1+t}-\ln(1+t)}$. See de Bruijn' "Asymptotic Methods in Analysis" (the example in section 4.7 is solved twice in the text - Laplace' method and Steepest descent, and it is reminiscent of your sum as it contains a sign-changing term).

The sign-changing property of your sum makes other nice methods obsolete. Hayman's method, for example, works in extracting the coefficients of $e^{P(t)}$ where $P$ is a function satisfying some positivity conditions ($\frac{t}{1+t}-\ln(1+t)$ is not admissible as its coefficients are sign-changing, but the method should succeed in approximating your sum if we remove the sign-changing term).

Comment: It is interesting that mention, analytic, since in particular,

Comment: Oh, I can't edit if I bump the post button on my phone.

Comment: All I was trying to say was, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = e^{-x} J_0(-2\sqrt{x})$, where $J_0$ is the Bessel function.